# JSON: output text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
{
    "items": {
        "phone": [{
            "product": "iPhone 8",
            "manufacturer": "Apple",
            "releaseDate": "2018",
            "price": 499
        }]
    }
};
```

I want it using JavaScript or jQuery like this:

[image: A mockup]

Thank you guys, you are blessed! :)

Comment: output here: <div id="content"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your `phone` items in your `info.items` object.

For each item, create a  phone `container` and append it to the `content`

The phone properties can be accessed like this `info.items[i].propertynamehere`. Here is the example, you can style it how you want, and structure it how you want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < info.items.phone.length; i++) {
    var phone = "<div class='phone'>" + info.items.phone[i].product + "</div>";
    $("#content").append(phone);
}
```

This uses `JQuery` so make sure to `include` that as well. If you would prefer a pure `Javascript` implementation, let me know and I can provide.

Comment: Thank you buddy, you gave me idea, cheers to you! let me know where can I donate for your effort???

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON.stringify method to turn the object into a string:

```js
var info = {
  "items": {
    "phone": [{
      "product": "iPhone 8",
      "manufacturer": "Apple",
      "releaseDate": "2018",
      "price": 499
    }]
  }
};

$("#content").text(JSON.stringify(info));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I doubt he wants to output the string, I imagine he wants to loop through, and parse data as needed. However the question lacks clarity.

Comment: This is the mockup I want to output the text!
http://s32.postimg.org/gesud83np/wireframe.png